# Hibernate, one to many from different table to general table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Good day.

Exists three tables(test):

```
User (id, user_name)
Object(id, object_name)
Property(id, property_value)
```

User, Object contain Property, so I'd like to use a special table EntityProperties(entity_id, entity_type, property_id), where entity_id - id from User or Object, and entity_type - user or object (params for tables User, Object).

May I implement it using Hibernate 4? If yes, please suggest with annotations and how better to do it.

Thanks,
Oleg

Answer (score 0):

if User is also an Object then it can be done by making User extends Object and then the problem becomes mapping inheritance which you can read more about [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)

If this is a one way relationship from a User to Property and from Object to property then I think it can be achieved by normal mapping (one to many) and then there is no need for the entity_type column since you'll only be querying the Property table with an entity_id in hand. This way a User object will have a field `Set<Property> properties;` and the same for the Object class.

Comment: Thanks, I know this solution, but in my case later I'll add another entities which will have Properties, so I thought not create every time additional table for links (for instance user_properties, object_properties and etc) but use entity_properties.

Comment: Actually im not suggesting that, what I suggest is a single properties table all entities with properties will reference this table. So one table referenced by many entities. but you can't have the relation revered (if you have a property you can't get its owner but if you have the owner you can get all its properties).

Comment: Sorry can't understand you, you offered to add fields like user_id, object_id to the Property table? Give me a sample please if I'm not right

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapped super class EntityPropertyMap which has a property object and have concrete implementations(UserPropertyMap and ObjectPropertyMap) with table per class hierarchy strategy. Examples can be found http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html and http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/

Comment: Example usage of table/class hierarchy is given in the link I shared earlier. Example for mappedsuperclass can be found here http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-mappedsuperclass-hibernate